# Changing .bashrc to allow a call to "android" from any directory

Tags: command-line, bash, android, bashrc

I can successfully do the following command in the directory listed

```
kn@MrComp:~/.android_os/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools$ android list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, WSVGA, WXGA800, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), WXGA720, WQVGA432, QVGA, WQVGA400, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
```

I have been following an instructional document which wanted me to edit my `.bash_profile` to include

```
export PATH=".:~/.android_os/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools:
               ~/.android_os/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools:$PATH"
```

But this does not work (I have opened a new terminal and tried). I also add that to my `.bashrc` file.

Is there anything thing else I can do to allow 'android' to be called from anywhere?

Comment: Use the full path (not "~") to the directory containing the "android" binary. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Thank you, that worked // Never mind I was still in the correct directory. It didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$HOME` instead of `~` and put it on one line (and I took out the leading `.` that's a bad idea because someone could put something in your current directory and you'll run that first - for example `sudo`) -

```
export PATH="$HOME/.android_os/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools:$HOME/.android_os/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools:$PATH"
```